# Pass a variable directly into a function in C?

Tags: c, scanf

As an example assume I have a function `double calculate(double input);` which takes `input` and adds `5.0` to it, then returns the value.

Say I wanted to take **user input**. Okay so create a variable to use with `scanf`, call it `double temp`. Then `scanf("%lf", &temp);` and finally we use the function `calculate(temp)`.

Is there any way to **pass the input directly into the function** `calculate` without having to setup a variable in the middle?

Comment: if you want, you can just call scanf from inside the function

Comment: Yes, good point. However I'm still curious about if what I described above is doable.

Comment: No. The `scanf` return is the number of conversion specifiers successfully matched, not the value of any one of them. There is no way to make `scanf` spit out the value you want.

Comment: You mean you want to access the local parameter as used inside the function, outside the function? Pfff, no. What you can do (but you shouldn't!) is make `temp` a global variable and use `calculate()` without parameters, thus using only `temp` and not `input`.

Comment: More or less I was just trying to see If I can _skip_ the step of creating a variable to store what the user inputs. (and then of course passing that variable into the function). Was trying to see if you could just _directly take the input_ and _pass it into the function_. Guess it's not possible and I'm sure there's good reasons why.

Comment: Maybe we should create some extension to C, where you could have a kind of struct with variables inside that could be accessed from the outside, and also functions inside that could be called. There's an idea.

Comment: @Insane No, not really. Even if you pass a pointer to `calculate`, you still need to get the input before you call `calculate`. It's a chicken-or-the-egg issue (actually a sequence issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible with `scanf()` because this function is designed to *parse* input in a format you choose, so it could have to assign multiple input values in one call. Note that it wouldn't change the compiled code anyway because, whether you create a variable or not, the real machine *has* to store the value *somewhere* for passing it to a function.

If you care instead about the shape of your C code, you can of course provide your own input function that *does* return the input, like e.g.

```
double getDoubleInput(void)
{
    double in;

    /* add sanity checks and whatever, following is just a stub ... */
    scanf("%lf", &in);
    return in;
}
```

and then use this instead. A good compiler would inline this if appropriate, so the generated code should stay roughly the same.